# List all subdirs and files in directory

Tags: c#, directory-structure, subdirectory, file-listing

I was wondering if anyone knows of a cleaner way to do this. I have a section of my program that will list all input directories that contain files.

However, to do this I manually store each input directory as a variable and use these as targets for the search.

I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

For example, the pseudo code I have in my head at the moment is:

- Starting at directory `Date`, `If FolderName == "Input"` then store all subfolders in array `InputSubs`
- For each folder in `InputSubs`, if no subfolder is contained within `InputSub` and no files are contained in `InputSubs` then move on to next
- If `InputSubs` contains a subdir, then store all subdirs in array `InputSubs2` and move on to next
- If `InputSubs` contains files, store `DirPath` and `FileName` as string in array `InputFiles`
- Repeat `InputSubs` process for `InputSubs2`

The deepest an input folder goes is 2 directories.

An example of the input folder structure is in the attached image.

[image]

An example of the code I currently use is as follows.

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear();

if (Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "AustraliaFolder")).Length != 0) 
{ 
     ListBox1.Items.Add(Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "AustraliaFolder"))[0]); 
}

if (Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "DE1Folder")).Length != 0) 
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "DE1Folder"))[0]); 
}

if (Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "PL1Folder")).Length != 0) 
{ 
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "PL1Folder"))[0]); 
}

if (Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "EuropeFolder")).Length != 0) 
{ 
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "EuropeFolder"))[0]); 
}

if (Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "fr1Folder")).Length != 0) 
{ 
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "fr1Folder"))[0]); 
}

if (Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "FranceFolder")).Length != 0) 
{ 
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "FranceFolder"))[0]); 
}

if (Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "HKFolder")).Length != 0) 
{ 
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "HKFolder"))[0]); 
}

if (Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "UKFolder")).Length != 0) 
{ 
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Directory.GetFiles(SalesInputFilePath + ResourceDetails.InputFolders(FormDMM, EH, ObjApp, Modules, "UKFolder"))[0]); 
}
```

I have an inescapable tendency to over complicate things and was wondering if there was an easier, or at least more efficient way to do it than the pseudo code from my head.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the final result you are interested in? A list of all files/all subfolders/both/a hierarchical structure that you can display in a treeview? Provide some sample output based on your screenshot.

Comment: essentially i am looking for my listbox to be populated with the full path and filename of any files that exist within the folder "Input" or one of its subfolders.

Comment: Oh - Ok, thats easy - see answer below

Comment: Copy + Paste - best friends ever :) Just make an array with AustraliaFolder, DE1Folder ,etc and iterate. For directories and sub directories, use recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> essentially i am looking for my listbox to be populated with the full path and filename of any files that exist within the folder "Input" or one of its subfolders. – DDuffy

All Files of a directory and it's subdirectories:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Your Input Direcotry","*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

> This does improve on my original code. thank you. However, i would need to duplicate this for every input directory. I wouldn't be able to use this from the base directory, as each folder in the base directory contains both an input and an output folder. Would there be a way to iterate through each Input folder found within the base directory? – DDuffy

```
public static List<string> GetAllFilesOfAllDirectoriesCalledInput(string root)
{
    List<string> inputDirectories = FindSubDirectoriesCalledInput(root);
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    foreach(string inputDirectory in inputDirectories)
        result.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(inputDirectory,"*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    return result;
}

public static List<string> FindSubDirectoriesCalledInput(string currentRoot)
{ 
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    foreach(string subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(currentRoot))
    {
        if(subDirectory.EndsWith("\\Input", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            results.Add(subDirectory);  
        else
            results.AddRange(FindSubDirectoriesCalledInput(subDirectory));
     }
     return results;
 }
```

Comment: This does improve on my original code. thank you. However, i would need to duplicate this for every input directory. I wouldn't be able to use this from the base directory, as each folder in the base directory contains both an input and an output folder. Would there be a way to iterate through each Input folder found within the base directory?

Comment: @DDuffy Split your search in two parts: Find Directories called `Input` and then list all Files in those directories.

Comment: BOOM! you star! this works fantastically. Its short, its sweet, and its much cleaner than the mess that's in my head at the moment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` to store the result, where the key fields stores the value of each directories and value fields stores the list of files in the corresponding directories. now take a look into the code:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (var item in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\search Directory", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    if (new DirectoryInfo(item).Name == "Input")
       dict.Add(item, getMyfiles(item));
}
```

This will loop through each directories and sub directories in the specified folder. in each iteration it calls the `getMyfiles()` which will return the files contained in the specified directory. We are collecting the directory name and the list of files in each iteration. Where the method `getMyfiles()` is defined like the following:

```
private List<string> getMyfiles(string DirectoryPath)
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, "*.*").ToList();
}
```

Comment: Just had a quick read up on "dictionary". Bit of a C# noob. Once the dictionary structure has been built, is there a way to see if the dictionary key contains the word "Input"?

Comment: yes you can check for input before adding: see the updation

Comment: This wouldn't work where the file was in a directory deeper than Input though would it? For example Input/FileDir/File.csv

Comment: There is a question mark at the end of the sentence. i wasn't saying it wouldn't work. I was asking. Apologies for the confusion. It was a guess from my limited knowledge of csharp. No i haven't tested it yet, i will as soon as i have a spare moment and get back to you. (Trying to test while at work.)

Comment: So I've managed to test this now. It will output the directory path for all folders named Input. however this will stop at the input folder. It may have something to do with the way i am outputting it to my listbox though. Would you know how to iterate through the dictionary to output the full path and file name of each file in an input folder. I tried ListBox1.Items.Add(item.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

```
var dirList = Directory.GetDirectories("Path", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(subdir => !Directory.GetDirectories(subdir).Any());
```

It will return you all directory name which contains files